# Make Internet Explorer recognize "advanced" CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

Do any JavaScript libraries exist that somehow make Internet Explorer (no particular version) recognize advanced CSS selectors, such as `input[type="text"]`?

I hate adding extra classes to HTML objects just to accommodate IE.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer? IE9 is pretty good with many selectors.

Comment: Also, `input[type=text]` isn't all that advanced, seeing as CSS2.1 has already been finalized as a W3C Recommendation after more than 10 years in development. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21 and IE supports that selector from version 7 and up.

Comment: @BoltClock That's why I put "advanced" in quotes ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, there doesn't exist a javascript library that can make the browser properly parse advance css (via style/stylesheets) that it doesn't already understand, that functionality needs to be baked into the browser itself.

Comment: input[type=text] is supported by IE6+

Comment: @venimus: No, only IE7+.

Comment: @Quintin Robinson: JavaScript can fix this, check out the answers here :)

Comment: @thirtydot Great suggestion, with the exception of missing `<style>` tags nested in the markup. Reminds me of the old "whatever:hover" script that would repair IE's limited capability from linked stylesheets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't believe this wasn't suggested:

http://selectivizr.com/

> selectivizr is a JavaScript utility
>   that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and
>   attribute selectors in Internet
>   Explorer 6-8. Simply include the
>   script in your pages and selectivizr
>   will do the rest.
>
> Selectivizr works automatically so you
>   don't need any JavaScript knowledge to
>   use it — you won't even have to modify
>   your style sheets. Just start writing
>   CSS3 selectors and they will work in
>   IE.

You also need to include a standard JavaScript library of your choice, which you're likely already doing.

Answer (score 7):

IE7.js (and IE8.js and IE9.js): http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ do their best to bring prior versions of IE up to support for what the script names (e.g. IE8.js tries to make IE6/7 act like IE8).  This includes, among other things, many attributes of CSS2/3, though you'll have to check to see exactly what is supported in which version.

if you just want to use the selectors in JS, http://sizzlejs.com/ supports all CSS2/3 selectors and is used as the base for many JS libraries.

Comment: I think that would work.  Thanks!  Your answer also led me to http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/enable_css_pseudo-element_selectors_in_internet_explorer_with_ie-css3.js/, which may be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

so you want a javascript that changes the browsers css support? 
 i'm pretty sure that's impossible.

your best bet is going to be putting whatever styles you want into a class, and in your document ready, do an .addClass